# Getting error while ng serve after updating angular, material and bootstrap

Tags: angular, themes, bootstrap-4, angular-material, angular-cli

**In packege.json:**

```
angular: 5.2.8
angular material : 5.1.1
angular/cli: "~1.7.3"
bootstrap: "~4.0.0"
```

> While ng serve, getting error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader??
embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8- 
3!./src/styles.scss
Module build failed:
```

[image]

Comment: Where and how do you import bootstraps scss files?

Comment: @Fussel in angular-cli.json: import `"styles/bootstrap.scss",` in styles

Answer (score -2):

After updating the package.json file you need to first run the install command to install the updated versions in the node_modules.

First run : npm install

Then run the application using : ng serve